# Registered but Anonymous comments

Tags: comments, user-registration, authentication

Is there a way / set of plugins that could enable discussion where each commenter is 'authenticated' with the site (via openid/fb/twitter/etc) but the commenter can still use a anonymous/fake name?

Basically we want to avoid people using other peoples email addresses and masquerading as them (in a university situation, its not difficult to work out someone else's email...)

Answer (score 1):

if you want the comments anonymous to the site's visitors, you could handle this in your comments template by simply not outputting any identifying information. display a name derived from their id, and only show the nickname if they enter one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Disqus or IntenseDebate or any one of the other commenting Plugins, and let the third-party service handle authentication? That way, users can control their level of anonymity.

If you just need to prevent email address impersonation (but don't need anonymity), use Gravatar.